# Not getting email when creating shipment through API in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipment-email

I am using API call to create order shipment.

**$ch = curl_init("https://store-url/index.php/rest/all/V1/order/17168/ship");**

It creates the shipment but not sending shipment email.

Please suggest me some idea.

thanks

Comment: Please check the log files. You will find the error or reason in the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notify field is used to trigger Magento to send the shipment email.

Found the answer [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-shipment.html):

So in order to send shipment email to customer, final call should be:

**$ch = curl_init("https://store-url/index.php/rest/all/V1/order/order_id/ship?notify=true");**